# Weird Mysql Increment

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, create-table

Mysql is auto incrementing by 6.  I am not sure why or how to even address the issues.

```
 create table new_table(tinyint unsigned primary key auto_increment, 
                        display_name varchar(50));
```

I've also used

```
 create table new_table(int unsigned primary key auto_increment, 
                        display_name varchar(50));
```

I don't think I am doing anything odd.

Comment: Is that the output from `show create table new_table`? If not, post that.

Comment: Sorry the second one should have been int not tiny int.  Also I just did show create and for some reason AUTO_INCREMENT=21.  I am not sure who that happened.

Comment: What's the result of `show variables like 'auto_inc%';`?

Comment: auto_increment_increment 6

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @RishikeshChandra When editing & composing: Please remove & don't add conversation like "hello" & "thanks", just ask the question. Also clarify via edits, not comments--so you should have edited in "AUTO_INCREMENT=21" & "auto_increment_increment 6"--except  those seem to both be mistakes. Your edit added nothing & shouldn't have been approved. Please read about editing under review in help & posts at meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @philipxy ......K

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have set auto_increment_increment to 6, if I understand your comment correctly.

- read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)

Note though, that this might be on purpose. Usually this is set in a master-master replication. One master is configured to use even numbers as auto_increment values, the other master uses the odd values.

To set it back to the usual behaviour of incrementing by 1, do the following:

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment = 1; /*or the SESSION value, depending on your needs*/
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_offset = 1; /*or SESSION value...*/
```

Also note, that having gaps in an auto_increment column is not a big deal. Should the column overflow, use bigint instead. Auto_increment columns can also have gaps because of rolled back transactions for example. When you want a strictly sequential numbering of your rows, don't rely on auto_increment!

Answer (score 0):

This should be the query

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `display_name` varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Also to set auto increment to 1 use

```
SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The database admin is using replication and failed to tell me.  I have never used replication so I was unaware of how incrementation worked.